# how to keep text in Textfield when you pop the page?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a text field, if i navigate.push to another page then come back to that same page all text in textfield clear...

i will want to keep the text i input in textfield should remain if i pop from the page..

**here is my code:**

```
  TextFormField(
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
controller: bioController,
  autofocus: false,
                                        keyboardType:TextInputType.multiline,
                                            maxLength: null,
                                            maxLines: null,
                                            expands: true,
                                            textAlignVertical:
                                                TextAlignVertical.top,
                                            validator: (text) {
                                              if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                                                return 'Text is empty';
                                              }
                                              return null;
                                            },
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                horizontal: 20,
                                                vertical: 10,
                                              ),
                                              hintText:
                                                  'Few words about yourselves',
                                              filled: true,
                                              fillColor:
                                                  Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 20,
                                                color:
                                                    Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                                              ),
                                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                    color:
                                                        Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
                                                    width: 1.0),
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                              ),
                                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                    color:
                                                        Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
                                                    width: 1.0),
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
```

here is the way i push to the next page:

after pushing to the next page then come back to the page all text clear

```
                      if (faith != null &&
                          status != null &&
                          ethnicity != null &&
                          nickName.text.isNotEmpty &&
                          profession.text.isNotEmpty &&
                          bioController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                          fullName.text.isNotEmpty) {
                        try {
                          await BioControllerApi().saveData(
                            age: age,
                            bio: bioController.text.trim(),
                            ethnicity: ethnicity,
                            faith: faith,
                            fullname: fullName.text.trim(),
                            profession: profession.text.trim(),
                            status: status,
                            username: nickName.text.trim(),
                          );
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (_) => TypeSlider(),
                            ),
                          );
```

thanks

Comment: How you're going to the new page from this page? Show your implementations

Comment: i have update to the question

Comment: why are you using ``Navigator.pushReplacement()`` use ``Navigator.push()``

Comment: okay i will try that..

Comment: 1. Don’t use push replacement. You are creating a whole new navigation stack when you do that. 2. Where is the text controller defined? It will persist the state of the text field so long as it’s in the stateful widget.

Comment: after using only push still yet is the form still clear data